# Does the order of fields in mongodb affect the query time (collscan)?

Tags: mongodb, bson

I observed that mongodb queries run much longer when I have some typo in a field name.
So my questions are:

1. How is the document stored in memory (after read) in mongo - as a hash table or linked list?
2. Is it possible that document is not read in total (from the beginning to the end) when the query require only first field? e.g col.find({some_field: "asdf"}, {some_field: 1}) can read only this one field from the bson file and skip reading the rest (in case when the document is very large). If it is like that, then a typo in field name force mongo to read whole bson and increase the time of collscan.

I know that indexes can change a lot in this case, so let's assume that there aren't any indexes on the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Q2:

> The BSON parser that MongoDB uses internally *only* does selective
> parsing. In fact it would be more correct to say it is an iterator
> over BSON fields than a parser of BSON objects. One of the important
> parts of BSON's design is that because every field is either
> fixed-size or prefixed with a size, it is easy to skip large swaths of
> BSON (eg, strings and whole subobjects) when looking for a field. This
> is unlike json, where you always need to examine every byte[1] until
> you find your desired field. If you are curious, you can see the logic
> for computing field size at
> https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/f27f82560f129f6ccd9b16fba887949ab197e678/src/mongo/bson/bsonelement.cpp#L709-L776,
> which is the meat of iterating over fields.

https://groups.google.com/g/bson/c/5u1WQ5kAtkc